# SSIS - Calculate Opening and Closing Balance

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, bids

I need to calculate the Opening Balance and the Closing Balance in SSIS. I have the below data as input.

```
invoice_date    amount
12/4/2016       4000
12/5/2016       5000
12/6/2016       7500
12/7/2016       5000
12/8/2016       8000
```

I want the output as below:

```
Opening Balance    4000
Closing Balance    8000
```

How can I achieve this in SSIS?

*Note: Need to do using only transformations. No Execute SQL task or OLEDEB command required.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In my answer i will assume that your Source is an `OLEDB Source` and your Destination is a `Flat File`*

You have to do the following steps:

1. Add another `Dataflow Task` *(assuming nema = `DFT Import`)*
2. In `DFT Import` Add your `OLEDB Source` , a `Script Component` and your `FlatFile Destination`
3. In The Script Component Mark `invoice_date` and `amount` columns as Input Columns

[image]

4. In the Script go to `Inputs and Outputs` Tab and make your `Output Buffer` asynchronous

[image]

5. Create 2 Output Columns *(`Desc` of type `DT_STR` and `amount` of TYPE `DT_I4`)

[image]

6. In your script write the following code: *(Vb.net)*

   ```
   Dim MinDate, MaxDate As Date
   Dim MinAmount, MaxAmount As Integer
   Dim intRowCount As Integer = 0
   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

       intRowCount += 1

       If intRowCount = 1 Then

           MinDate = Row.invoicedate
           MaxDate = Row.invoicedate
           MinAmount = Row.amount
           MaxAmount = Row.amount

       Else

           If Row.invoicedate < MinDate Then

               MinDate = Row.invoicedate
               MinAmount = Row.amount

           ElseIf Row.invoicedate > MaxDate Then

               MaxDate = Row.invoicedate
               MaxAmount = Row.amount

           End If

       End If

   End Sub

   Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
       MyBase.PostExecute()

       Output0Buffer.AddRow()
       Output0Buffer.Desc = "Opening Balance"
       Output0Buffer.amount = MinAmount


       Output0Buffer.AddRow()
       Output0Buffer.Desc = "Closing Balance"
       Output0Buffer.amount = MaxAmount

   End Sub
   ```
7. Map your output Columns to the Destination Columns

*Note: if your source column datatypes are not `datetime` and `integer` you have to perform some casting method in the script*

**OTHER METHOD**

1. Add an `Execute SQL Task` to get the row coubt of the source Table
2. Store the count value *(Resultset)* into a SSIS Variable *(ex: `User::intCount`)*

*you can use a dataflow task containing an `OLEDB Source` and a `Rowcount` component instead of the first two steps and store rowcount result into a variable*

3. Follow the same steps from the first method
4. In the script add `User::intCount` as a Readonly Variables
5. In the script write the following Code

   ```
   Dim MinDate, MaxDate As Date
   Dim MinAmount, MaxAmount As Integer
   Dim intRowCount As Integer = 0
   Dim intCurrentRow As Integer = 0

   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

       intCurrentRow += 1

       If intCurrentRow = 1 Then

           MinDate = Row.invoicedate
           MaxDate = Row.invoicedate
           MinAmount = Row.amount
           MaxAmount = Row.amount

       Else

           If Row.invoicedate < MinDate Then

               MinDate = Row.invoicedate
               MinAmount = Row.amount

           ElseIf Row.invoicedate > MaxDate Then

               MaxDate = Row.invoicedate
               MaxAmount = Row.amount

           End If

           If intCurrentRow = intRowCount


           Output0Buffer.AddRow()
           Output0Buffer.Desc = "Opening Balance"
           Output0Buffer.amount = MinAmount

           Output0Buffer.AddRow()
           Output0Buffer.Desc = "Closing Balance"
           Output0Buffer.amount = MaxAmount

          End If

       End If

   End Sub

   Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()
       MyBase.PreExecute()

       IntRowCount = Variables.intCount

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: I followed your steps.. But I am not gettng any output

Comment: @YousufSultan Getting any exception? Or script component not showing any output?

Comment: @YousufSultan i added another method, take a look

Comment: @YousufSultan waiting for ur reply??